# Why does the protagonist write from left to right?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-spy

*Note: This Question does not contain much of a spoiler, as it is from S1E1, but answers might, so please declare if so.*

In *The Spy*, in one of the early scenes, the protagonist is shown in a prison cell, apparently tortured on both hands, writing a letter.

He does so, from left to right, with his left hand.

[image]

Since he is of Arab heritage, and a Jew, I expected him to write from right to left in any case.

**I do not believe this is a mishap, is there an explanation for him writing left to right (either in or out of universe)?**

Comment: It seems obvious from the screen capture that he's writing in English, a language that's both written and read from left to right.  The real question appears to be "Is the character writing in English, or is English being used as a device to help the viewer's understanding of this plot item?"

Comment: @Snow The white visualization at the upper edge of the paper is some form of "subtitle" and animated, thus more of a visual effect, but at the end of the scene, the paper is filled with ink, so the character actually writes to the paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's revealed at the end of episode S1:E6.

> The reason is, it's written in French. It remains a mystery to me why he chose French, but it seems it does not matter to the plot at all.